# Is there any way to upload a file in database without using Part class?

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets

I'm developing a Google App Engine application in eclipse indigo. I'm trying to upload a word file in database using HTML file input, but it seems that my servlet version is below 3.0  and I can't use methods like `getPart()`. Is there any other way to this?

Comment: Why don't you use servlets in version higher than 3.0? I'm using `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0` without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with the blobstoreService?

```
Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);
```

To see more about it you can check here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/